# How to autogenerate documentation of API for Websocket Spring Boot Java project?

Tags: java, documentation, spring-websocket

I'm in need to find some easy to use solution for documentation autogeneration such as Spring Rest Docs is.

Is there any option to do this on WebSocket API without using Oracle Javadoc?